# What is the plural of 'Cuba Libre' (the beverage)?

Tags: plurales

For example, how would one say 'More Cuba Libres' in Spanish?

Comment: Not really relevant, as almost no one will understand what "Cuba Libre" is. In Spanish it's "cubata".

Answer (score 5):

I mostly hear *Cuba libres*, my view point is that of a native speaker, not a linguist, so it may not be right, but in matters of languages, how the *living* language is, is sometimes more important that what books say.

One clear example is *Medialunas* ( literally *half-moon*, means croissant ) although sometimes but not often, I've heard *medias lunas*

Answer (score 2):

You can either write Cuba Libre as:

- **Cuba Libre**: in this case the plural is either *Cubas Libres* or *Cubas-Libres*.
- **cubalibre**: in this case the plural can only be *cubalibres*.

Comment: never heard someone saying _Cubas Libres_, not in South America at least

Comment: I haven't either, but it's grammatically correct.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the difference between proper and common Spanish. In proper Mexican Spanish a proper name is never pluralized. For example if there are 3 people named Jose in a room you say “Dale la sopa a los Jose nomas.” Give the soup to the Joses only; this is because the name always refers to an individual that cannot be plural. It may sound funny but the proper way to say it is “Dame 3 Cubalibre para mis compañeros”. The rules for when to use the plural are very specific in proper Spanish. I found an example back in a previous question about “Buenas Noches.” The proper form is if you are addressing an individual you say “Que tengas una buna noche” now if you are addressing a group you say “Tengan buenas noches” it is plural because the night refers to each person so multiple people have there individual night.

Comment: according to RAE (section 2.8 of this link: http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=plural) the plural of proper names is done as the general rules, so it should be "los Josés". You can see there examples: "las Cármenes, los Pablos..."

Comment: I see your correction and by the RAE you are correct. I was taught never to pluralize a proper name obviously incorrect. My Spanish is old school I will refrain from further answers.

Comment: @Fortunato Whilst I guess following the RAE is preferred, I still found your answer interesting, and will possibly be useful if I ever come across this use.